# Where does light come from in a Cycles scene without lamps?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

Using the Blender Render, if you have no lamps, the objects are black.  With Cycles Render, even without any lamps, there is a small amount of light.

Here is a render of the same yellow monkey without any lamps present using the two render engines:

[image: Comparison of renders of the same scene using Blender Internal and Cycles]

Where does this light come from?  Can you turn it off?

Comment: Your profile mentions what is probably [videos]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In cycles the *World* emits light. You can turn this off by setting the world color to black, or setting the *Strength* to `0` in *Properties > World*:

[image]

If you still want the background to appear as a color besides black, you can make the world emit light only for the camera by mixing two *Background* shaders based on the *Is Camera Ray* output of the [*Light Path*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/light_path.html#light-path-node) node:

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Or you can also set "film" to transparent in the render panel, and add a color in the compositor with "RGB" and "Alpha Over" nodes ;)

Comment: @Polosson You can, but I think this way is faster if you are not doing any compositing already.